# How to add random noise to a signal using NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, random, noise

I want to add Gaussian random noise to a variable in my model for each separate time-step and not to generate a noise array and add it to my signal afterwards. In this way I want to examine a standard dynamic effect of my system.

So, I want to generate each time-step a random noise (i.e. a single value) and it to my signal (e.g. add noise then it calculates the next state, add noise it calculates the next state, etc.). I thought to do this via NumPy using the following in the dynamic section of my model over a set of time-steps:

```
self.x = self.x + self.a * ((d-f)/100)

self.x = self.x + np.random.normal(0, 0.5, None)`
```

the second line is drawing random samples from a normal distribution and adds it to my variable.

`0` is the mean of the normal distribution I am choosing from, `0.5` is the standard deviation of the normal distribution and the third argument is the size.

I am wondering if `numpy.random.normal` is the correct way to do it and, if so, what parameter I should use for the size argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate a single number, use the 2-argument form of `np.random.normal`:

```
In [47]: np.random.normal(0, 0.5)
Out[47]: 0.6138972867165546
```

You may need to scale this number (multiply it by a small number `epsilon`) so the noise is small compared to `self.x`.